# Number of quarters, dimes and nickles.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I'm solving a problem which states the following;

> Mary has $3.00 in nickels, dimes, and quarters. If she has twice as
>   many dimes as quarters and five more nickels than dimes, how many
>   coins of each type does she have?

I transcribed the relationships as such;
$2q=d, n=d+5$

And i need to solve the following;

$
3 = 0.01n+0.1d+0.25q \therefore\\
3=0.01(d+5)+0.1(2q)+0.25q \therefore\\
3=0.01d+0.45q+0.05 \therefore\\
3=0.01(2q)+0.45q+0.05\therefore\\
3=0.47q+0.05\therefore\\
2.95 = 0.47q \therefore\\
6.4 = q
$

I've checked the answer online, but im interested and why this method failed. I'm not aware of rules i broke here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One nickel is $5$ cents.

The equation is

$$3=0.0\color{red}5n+0.1d+0.25q$$

$
3 = 0.05n+0.1d+0.25q \therefore\\
3=0.05(d+5)+0.1(2q)+0.25q \therefore\\
3=0.05d+0.45q+0.25 \therefore\\
3=0.05(2q)+0.45q+0.25\therefore\\
3=0.55q+0.25\therefore\\
2.75 = 0.55q \therefore\\
5= q
$

Comment: oh wow, what an ignorant mistake. Sorry Americans.